# How to install PySide in raring

Tags: installation, pyside

What is the easiest way to install PySide in Ubuntu 13.04?
There is a link to a PPA in their binary packages section but it does not have packages for Raring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only just noticed that there's a raft of `python-pyside` packages in the repos. Currently version 1.1.2 (the same as their latest PPA version for Precise).

```
$ apt-cache search ^python3?-pyside
python-pyside - Python bindings for Qt4 (big metapackage)
python-pyside.phonon - Qt 4 Phonon module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtcore - Qt 4 core module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtdeclarative - Qt 4 Declarative module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtgui - Qt 4 GUI module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qthelp - Qt 4 help module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtnetwork - Qt 4 network module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtopengl - Qt 4 OpenGL module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtscript - Qt 4 script module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtsql - Qt 4 SQL module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtsvg - Qt 4 SVG module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qttest - Qt 4 test module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtuitools - Qt 4 UI tools module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtwebkit - Qt 4 WebKit module - Python bindings
python-pyside.qtxml - Qt 4 XML module - Python bindings
python3-pyside - Python3 bindings for Qt4 (big metapackage)
python3-pyside.phonon - Qt 4 Phonon module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtcore - Qt 4 core module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtdeclarative - Qt 4 Declarative module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtgui - Qt 4 GUI module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qthelp - Qt 4 help module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtnetwork - Qt 4 network module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtopengl - Qt 4 OpenGL module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtscript - Qt 4 script module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtsql - Qt 4 SQL module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtsvg - Qt 4 SVG module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qttest - Qt 4 test module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtuitools - Qt 4 UI tools module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtwebkit - Qt 4 WebKit module - Python3 bindings
python3-pyside.qtxml - Qt 4 XML module - Python3 bindings
```

---

Regarding the installation issues, if you have extra repositories installed, they may be borking up the process. Make sure your `apt-cache policy python-pyside` looks vaguely like the following:

```
python-pyside:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.1.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages
```

If you have extra sources and they're providing the candidate and they don't work, that'll break installation.

Comment: It says `Package python-pyside is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-pyside' has no installation candidate`

Comment: That isn't what it says here. I've added an edit about sources.

Comment: For me it looks like this `python-pyside:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
` So, what should I do now? I have removed the PPA.

Comment: @apandada1 That suggests you don't have the universe repository enabled. [Fix that here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

Comment: ♦ I do have universe enabled.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi What you're describing (having raring universe enabled and not being able to see the package) is not possible unless this is a brand new machine that hasn't updated its package list. Run a `sudo apt-get update` and then try installing.